# Replace version number in a string using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a bundle version set in a file, like this:

```
"dist/app-build-v1.08": {
```

How can I sed the version number and swap it out with an incremented  number?

First I'm attempting to grab the line itself, which is the third line in my bundle file.

```
BUILD=$(sed '3q;d' ./build/bundles.js)
```

Which does indeed grab the line. I found this snippet here on stack overflow:

```
's/[^0-9.]*\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/'
```

Which i'd like to use on $BUILD, but it doesn't work. The expected output for me would be

```
$NUM = "1.08"
```

Then I'd like increment it to 1.09, rebuild the string and used `sed -i` to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the interesting line is always line 3. Then you can use this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==3{gsub(/[^.0-9]+/,"");$0+=0.01;print}' file.js
```

- This line focuses on line3, and take the version number, add `0.01` to it.
- Assume that your version format is always `x.xx`. If it is not in this case, it is also possible to calculate the increment dynamically. like `0.01 or 0.00001` But extra implementation is required.
- If you run it with your example file, it will give you `1.09`

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

```
sed -r '3s/.*build-v([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*/\1+0.01/' | bc -q
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '"dist/app-build-v1.08": {' | sed -r 's/.*build-v([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*/\1+0.01/' | bc -q
1.09
```